# How to select (cherry-pick) files in Files using keyboard only? (Juno)

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm used to navigating myself using the keyboard through the [files](/questions/tagged/files) app, and until [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno), I could select particular files in a folder by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Looks like in `Juno`, this shortcut has changed to open the file I'm trying to additionally select after the first one selected.

Is there any way to make it behave as earlier, or is there another shortcut that could be used to select particular files?

Note: I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Click</kbd>, but I'm interested in a solution not involving using a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a regression :-(. You can select the item under the cursor using `<Ctrl><Alt>plus` or `<Ctrl><Alt>equal` (and deselect with `<Ctrl><Alt>minus`) but there does not seem to be a way of moving the cursor to another item without losing the existing selection and without selecting the new item under the cursor.

I'll raise an issue on GitHub.

The problem with `<Ctrl><Space>` is that it clashes with the shortcut to change the input method.

Comment: This only applies to Icon View.  If you switch to List View or Column View, you can cherry pick files using the above-mentioned shortcuts and moving the cursor with `<Ctrl><Up>` and `<Ctrl><Down>`

Comment: Issue tracked at: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/800

Comment: A fix for this awaiting review.